# How to pass string from one fragment to another in android

Tags: android, string, android-fragments, store, message-passing

I have two fragments and i want to send fragment2 string to fragment1 and store it in a string in fragment1. When i try to do this in a normal way it shows me a error which i have posted down. Someone please help me.

Fragment2.class

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", value);//value= my value from code
Fragmentclass2 frag2=new Fragmentclass2();
frag2.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fragment1.class

```
 final String store= getArguments().getString("message");
```

Error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: You are setting your bundle in a Fragmentclass2... shouldn't it be Fragmentclass1? Also, be sure you are displaying the instance of the object you are setting the argument

Answer (score 2):

**I recommend to use this way**

when you pass the data from first fragment

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString(Constants.ROOM," room")

val fragment= GroupRoomDevicesFragment()
fragment.arguments=bundle
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fl_automate, fragment)
            .addToBackStack("name")
            .commit()
```

when you get the data from another fragment

```
var screentext=requireArguments().getString(Constants.ROOM)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the `newInstance()` fragment general practice.

For that you should consider to create the `newInstance()` method in your `Fragmentclass1`like this:

```
public static Fragmentclass1 newInstance(String value) {
    Fragmentclass1 fragmentclass1 = new Fragmentclass1();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("message", value);
    fragmentclass1.setArguments(args);

    return fragmentclass1;
}
```

In your `Fragmentclass2` you call:

```
Fragmentclass1.newInstance("YOUR_MESSAGE")
```

this will create the `Fragmentclass1` so the last thing to do is to retrieve the arguments in the onCreate of the `Fragmentclass1`. Like you were doing:

```
final String store= getArguments().getString("message");
```

Comment: Can you answer clearly. I mean clear code using instance and all

Comment: I am using fragments for tabs. So i need a code based on this

Comment: Did you tried the things to replicate my answer in your code? You just have to do the things exactly as it is in the answer. Just to make it clear the only thing you should replace is `"YOUR_MESSAGE"` with the things you want to pass between those fragments

Comment: Fragmentclass1.newInstance("YOUR_MESSAGE") is not working. newInstance() function is not working

Comment: Have you defined the static method `newInstance()` in the `Fragmentclass1` as I said in my answer? Don't forget that the method must be static.. You can copy and past from my answer and it will work for sure.